# How can I detect a user's computer/browser session for auth purposes

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, passport.js

I am trying to implement a login system that sends a confirmation email to the user in case he logs in from a new computer/browser.

I am using Nodejs, AngularJS and PassportJS.

Any pointers to where I could find resources for this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The client side can detect stuff like os/browser, so you can just POST that data up to the server whenever the client loads. Other than that, you can match usernames with IP-adresses, but if you're storing that kind of information you ought to hash the information before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as setting a session variable (https://github.com/expressjs/session)

```
if(req.user){ // so that it only triggers when the user has actually logged in
    if(!req.session.thisBrowser) {
        req.session.thisBrowser = true || 'this computer/browser' || 'whatever';
        req.user.email('You have been logged in from ...'); // do your thing
    }
}
```