# Getting user computer/browser for authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, browser, oauth

I would like to send users a confirmation email before authenticating from a new computer/browser.

Any pointers to resources on this or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

I am using nodejs, angularjs and passportjs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect a user's computer/browser session for auth purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464852/how-can-i-detect-a-users-computer-browser-session-for-auth-purposes)

Comment: Oh! The app bugged on me, damn

Comment: After posting it said the question did not exist, and I didn't find out how to see my latest questions on the app